# Android ftp download failure from HTC to Samsung

Tags: android

i had uploaded .3gp videofile from HTC legent using FTP and download it in samsung but the download file shows unsupported.But when use same mobile for upload and download it works fine.can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

The procedure of uploading or downloading a file and its format may vary from phone to phone.